# Magento Logged Error:“ Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in…”

Tags: error, log

I'm getting a logged error withing my magento backend for this about every 5 mins an its using up a lot of my site memory because of how frequently this error is logged. What should I do to fix this error?

I have been given a filename and line :

`FrontendConfigurableProductMatrix/controllers/CartController.php` on line 55

here is the code for lines 50-60:

```
unset($params['product_matrix']);

$product_matrix = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_matrix');

if (count(array_filter($product_matrix['qty'])) == 0) {
    if(count($params['super_attribute']) != 0 && count($params['super_attribute']) == count(array_filter($params['super_attribute']))) {
        $product_matrix = array();
        $product_matrix['qty'] = array( $params['product'] => $params['qty']);
        $product_matrix[$params['product']] = $params;
    } else {
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is purely PHP based question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your first `if` in an other `if`

```
if (isset($product_matrix['qty']) && is_array($product_matrix['qty'])) {
    //...your code here
} else {
    //...some other code that handles the case when $product_matrix['qty'] is not an array.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Disclaimer : This is pure PHP Question and hence not a suitable thread
>   here.

Use this:

```
unset($params['product_matrix']);

$product_matrix = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_matrix');

if (is_array($product_matrix['qty']) && count(array_filter($product_matrix['qty'])) == 0) {
    if(count($params['super_attribute']) != 0 && count($params['super_attribute']) == count(array_filter($params['super_attribute']))) {
        $product_matrix = array();
        $product_matrix['qty'] = array( $params['product'] => $params['qty']);
        $product_matrix[$params['product']] = $params;
    } else {
```

Here `is_array($product_matrix['qty'])` will make sure variable passed to `array_filter` function is an array.